# How do I force Gmail desktop notifications to open the tab and not pop up out into mini modal view?

Tags: gmail

I use Gmail Desktop notifications all the time because I have 837284 apps open and the browser is not always in view and in focus. But my issue is that when I click on the notification/toast, it spawns a mini modal Chrome window and does not, instead, bring into focus the full Gmail tab that I have open, with the that particular email instance.

The desktop alerts for Google voice seem to work properly, as in they do bring the tab with Google Voice into focus and activate the alerted instance. Not sure why Gmail is not behaving the same way.